# Get data from the db to the view page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database

I am working on live support project for a web site. I just wrote the frontend and I created the table that I need in SQL Server and then I made a connection between SQL Server and my ASP.NET MVC project.

I watched many videos and I didn't get the part which I will start get the data from the models which are created when I made the connection I talked about.

To be clear: I wrote two Divs in web page one for the sender and one for the receiver and I give messages a variable called ̰"destination" in DB so if the value is 0 it will be insert the text in sender's div and if the value is 1 it will be insert the text in receiver's div.

The problem that I know the logic but I don't know how to apply it. Please can anyone help me and tell me how to do it? Or what is the Technique that I should work with?

Answer (score 0):

You should start looking into Entity Framework to get the data from the database. I think for now you should use Database First approach which is very easy as compared to Code first approach.

To start with Database first just add new item and select **ADO.NET Entity Model** . This will launch the wizard where you can select **EF designer from database** and then you can give the connection string and all the databse you want to use

Refer below link for explanation.

http://debugonweb.com/2020/01/crud-operation-using-database-first-approach-asp-net-mvc/